# No matching function to call - compiler says I call (QObject *&) when call is (QObject *)

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals, qmetaobject

This is the code:

```
void invokeQMLFunction2Arg(QObject * object, QString func, QVariant p1, QVariant p2) {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, func, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, p1), Q_ARG(QVariant, p2));
}
```

This is the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject*&, QString&, Qt::ConnectionType, QArgument<QVariant>, QArgument<QVariant>)'
```

What am I missing? I call `invokeMethod()` with a pointer, yet the compiler complains it is a pointer reference.

Comment: "I call invokeMethod() with a pointer" The "a pointer" you refer to doesn't exist. You're passing a reference to a pointer, perhaps even a const reference or an rvalue reference, but still. The compiler is correct. Passing arguments by value works by passing a const reference (or an rvalue reference) that is then used to initialize a function-local copy of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a QString to the second argument, whereas that should be `const char*`. Convert that to the proper type because there is no implicit conversion. You need to decide which way to convert it to `QByteArray` first, so this is one example that you could potentially write:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, func.toUtf8().constData(), Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, p1), Q_ARG(QVariant, p2));
```

Comment: I was referring to your initial answer. Anyway, I still don't understand why passing a string would make GCC report that I call with a pointer reference... I incorrectly assumed QString auto-casts to `char *`, but why the `QObject *&`?

Comment: Dunno the details... gcc is nuts :)

Comment: @user2341104 Because `object` is an lvalue. The compiler didn't say you passed a `QObject*&`, it said you tried to call a function which could _accept_ a `QObject*&`.

Comment: @Oktalist: yes, but this is not what it should be an in ideal world IMHO.

Comment: @LaszloPapp what would you prefer instead? (I don't think OP posted the entire error, anyway.)

Comment: @Oktalist: thanks for asking. I would prefer to just complain about the QString versus char *, so the rest would look like in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I have met with the same question. and My problem is actually cause by other factors. I move one of my program  from QT 4 to QT 5, and I did not declare QDialog explicitly, so when I call the method, there is the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QDialog*&, const char [12],     Qt::ConnectionType)'
```

and I see the compile output, the error message is,

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QDialog*' to 'QObject*'
```

suddenly, I realized that I do not declare the Qdialog.
QT sometimes can not give a really good compile error output, I think.